# WordPress 301 redirect loop issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm keeping an existing WordPress website but changing the domain name. The old domain name will be redirected to the same website, so if someone went to https://oldexample.com they would arrive at https://newexample.com.

From what I have read will need to do a 301 redirect from the old slugs to the new URLs, like this:

```
redirect 301 /old-page/ https://newexample.com/new-page
```

But in every article I've read online this approach assumes that the old slug is named something different to the slug.

But in my case, all of the pages have the same slug but will have a different domain. For example: A slug from the old domain might be my-cool-page and with the new domain there is also a page called my-cool-page, and according to what I've read I would need to do this:

```
redirect 301 /my-cool-page/ https://newexample.com/my-cool-page
```

But, and here is my question: Wouldn't this cause a redirect loop? Or can I simply get away with this:

```
redirect 301 https://oldexample.com/my-cool-page/ https://newexample.com/my-cool-page
```

Comment: Hey. Seen my answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only rule you need in .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)oldexample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will cover **all** your URLs. The approach you were using would not only cause a redirection loop, but would need a new rule per each URL. Not very efficient.

Since it's Wordpress, and Wordpress saves URLs in the DB, you'll need to do a search & replace of the old domain in the DB and replace it with the new one.

There are many tools and/or plugins to do that. The best, IMO, is [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/). Using it you would just need to execute

```
wp search-replace https://oldexample.com https://newexample.com
```

from the command line, and you'd be ready to roll.

Comment: Awesome, that's way better. And I assume I can still use the `redirect 301 /old-page/ https://newexample.com/new-page method` when required? I've since learned that we need to remove a couple of the existing pages, and so I'd like to redirect those to somewhere else.

PS: Well aware of the WordPress database URL thing, but thanks for mentioning it so that others may benefit if they read this.